# Innobackup script throws file not found error

Tags: mysql, percona, innobackupex

I'm trying to run innobackup script to perform full backup on a MySQL docker instance using the following script:

```
innobackupex --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/ -s --host=node1 --port=31057 --user=root --password=abc --compress --compress-threads=8 --stream=xbstream --parallel=4  ./ > /data/mysql-backup/2017-05-22/full/backup.xbstream
```

I have a database named abc and while executing the above script, its throwing the following error:

```
innobackupex: File './abc/tracking_rule.frm' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
[01] error: cannot open file ./abc/tracking_rule.frm
[01] Error: copy_file() failed.
Failed to copy file ./abc/tracking_rule.frm"
```

I can see the file physically present in the datadir.

Moreover `cksum ./abc/tracking_rule.frm` failed. It gave the error:
No file or directory

Comment: Do you know if mysql has the rights to write to `./abc/tracking_rule.frm`

Comment: Yes, it has the right to write.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe your disk is full?

Comment: Its not full. It has more than 25G available, and my datadir is only 1.1G

Comment: does mysql have the rights to read?

Comment: yes, mysql has read and write permission.